# TyperError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, undefined, typeerror, watch, servicenow

Our team is using angularjs to develop a ServiceNow widget and we are seeing "TyperError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" in our console:

[image]

When we click on "at eval", it takes us to this particular snippet of code with line 321 highlighted:

[image]

We can't seem to figure out what's causing that error.  We are using $watch on an array ($scope.data.list) and have read that $watchCollection might be better, but we tried that with no change.  Any ideas what could be causing this error and how to get rid of it?

Comment: your error is saying `$scope.data.list` is undefined, and so when you try and use `.length` of undefined you'll get your error. What do you see if you `console.log($scope.data)` ? How are you updating `$scope.data.list` ?

Comment: Just check the data, .length wont give error if the data is there where you are using it. Do a `typeof` and check the data as well.

Comment: Pictures of code are difficult to read, makes it difficult to reproduce the problem, or to copy to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have posted, you haven't defined or nor declared
`$scope.data.list` (I'm assuming `$scope.data` is defined somewhere). To
resolve that, you need to at least declare your `$scope.data.list` first to watch over it.

Coming to the `$watch` part, it depends on what your requirement is.
`$scope.$watchCollection` looks for changes made in the array as well as elements  whereas,
`$scope.$watch` will only look for changes made if the array is totally
assigned to a different one. Otherwise, if you want to watch deep, you can
use `$scope.$watch` with a boolean `true` variable passed as a third
argument to it.

Refer this link for the full documentation - https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge `$watch` on `$scope.data.list` called whenever any value changed in this collection

So by looking at error it seems like `$scope.data.list` `list` in no longer exits  in `$scope.data`. Try to find out where `$scope.data` is going to change.

And use below syntax for watch on collection

```
$scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newList,oldList) {
   if(newList && newList.length) {
      $scope.data.list = newList.length;
   }
});
```